# Photoshop: Stretch Image at a custom angle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

How do I broaden the face without reorienting the picture and therefore losing image quality?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your layer to smart object. Then rotate it so that the wanted stretching direction is horizontal. Rotate it back to the needed angle position. Only the stretching will increase apparent blurriness because the needed deformations are always calculated from that data which was valid just when the smart object was created. Make them as soon as you expect repeating stretchings and rotations to be needed.

You cannot do pixel colors affecting edits to smart objects except with adjustment layers or opening the image inside the object to a different window. For full editability Smart objects must be rasterized. But they are a way to non-destructive deformations and filterings.

ADD: Without smart objects it's possible with warping or in simple cases with Edit > Transform > Distort. Drag the vertical edges of the bounding box to the wanted direction. Be sure you have in move tool options Show Transform Controls =ON

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

This is useful for small stretches, long stretches like this lose its linearity.

Comment: Yes I know I should have set it as a Smart Object at start. But simply stretching it into a direction other than horizontal or vertical? You are saying it's not possible?

Comment: I added a little to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Generally, every time you stretch an image you lose quality.

Comment: Please delete this answer

Comment: @AzulShiva why the answer is true. Anyway the transformation does not actually degrade until you accept it so even if you rotate scale and rotate back it does not degrade more than it would if yous scale would do itt directly. It only degrades if you dont hit enter in between

Comment: @joojaa well how do I do it without hitting enter? That's what the question is about lol. The pointless remark by Lucian will just prevent actual answers.

Comment: @AzulShiva if you change the transform tool it just appends that to current transform. Its not untill you exit that it gets rendered out

Comment: @joojaa Yes but I still can't stretch the picture diagonally because the transform tool rotates and moves with the picture

Comment: @AzulShiva rotate scale then reverse rotate

Comment: @joojaa What? No

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90522/discussion-between-joojaa-and-azulshiva).

Comment: In the professional world, when an image is too small you just replace it with something else. If its a personal picture, use a bigger camera :)